# ImageMagick 6.7.7 conversion from RGB PDF to CMYK PDF looks dark

Tags: imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick 6.7.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

I am converting an RGB PDF to CMYK PDF and it looks dark. But it is working fine with ImageMagick 6.6.6.

I am using below command:

```
convert tp_rgb.pdf -verbose -density 300 -colorspace CMYK  tp_cmyk.pdf
```

How can we fix that? Can any help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) sample input image? Can you provide the results from both IM 6.6.6 and IM 6.7.7?

Answer (score 4):

At version 6.7.6, ImageMagick started treating grayscale images without colorspace information as "linear" instead of "sRGB" by default, with the result that they looked darker.  Later, the default was switched back to "sRGB" and a few related problems were fixed.  Upgrading to version 6.8.9 or later will restore the original, expected behavior, where all images are handled as "sRGB" by default.

Comment: There's a ton on the Internet about this problem, but this is the only solution that actually worked for me.  And bonus points for it being super simple.  Incidentally, if you're running on Heroku and you upgrade to the Cedar-14 stack from the  Cedar-10 stack, you almost certainly have this problem.  Just putting that here for some good Google foo.